# $\psi:A\rightarrow A^{-1}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Define a map that takes a matrix to it's inverse. Give $A\in M(n\times n)$ over reals field, define:
$$\psi:A\rightarrow A^{-1}$$
Is it always continuous, where defined? How do I prove this?

Thanks.

Comment: A hint that might help or not, depending on what you know, is to think about Cramer's rule.

Comment: I am familiar with Cramer's Rule for 2 or 3 dimensional square matrices and can wildly guess how would the argument look like but it's difficult to exactly visualize a proof.

Comment: Maybe that's not so helpful then. Can you at least see why the statement is true in the dimensions when you do know Cramer's rule? (I'm only stressing this Cramer's rule thing because that's how I know to prove this statement, but there are almost certainly other ways).

Comment: Thank you. I see where this goes (with some help from answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could argue that, according to Cramer's rule, the matrix $A^{-1}$ is given by $$\frac{1}{\det A} Adj(A)$$ where Adj(A) is the adjugate matrix of A. Now, every element of Adj(A) is just a polynomial of the coefficients of the matrix A, and therefore continuous. Similarly, $\det(A)$ is also a polynomial in the coefficients of the matrix A. This should be enough to conclude what we need to.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that does not rely on Cramer's rule or properties of the determinant.

If $\|\cdot\|$ satisfies $\|AB\| \le \|A \| \|B\|$, then if $\|X\| < 1$, we have $(I+X)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kX^k$.

So we have $(A+H)^{-1} = (A(I+A^{-1}H))^{-1} = (I+A^{-1}H)^{-1} A^{-1}$. Using the above identity, and assuming that $\|H\| < \frac{1}{\|A^{-1} \|}$ (which imples $\|A^{-1}H\| < 1$), we have
$(A+H)^{-1} = (\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (A^{-1}H)^k) A^{-1}$.
Hence we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
\|A^{-1} - (A+H)^{-1} \| &\le& \sum_{k=1}^\infty \|H\|^k \|A^{-1}\|^{k+1} \\
&=& \|H\| \|A^{-1}\|^{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\|H\| \|A^{-1}\|)^{k-1} \\
&\le& \|H\| \frac{\|A^{-1}\|^{2}}{1-\|H\| \|A^{-1}\| }
\end{eqnarray}
If we assume $\|H\| < \frac{1}{2\|A^{-1} \|}$, the above estimate simplifies to 
$\|A^{-1} - (A+H)^{-1} \| \le 2 \|A^{-1}\|^{2} \|H\|$, from which it follows that the operator $A \mapsto A^{-1}$ is continuous.

The above shows that, in fact, the operator $A \mapsto A^{-1}$ is smooth.

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the proof.

Comment: You are welcome; however, I didn't mean you to change your selected answer, the purpose was just to provide an alternative to the other answer...